# How to extract block comments from a string using regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, comments

I want to write a function that takes a string and returns an array with the content of all the block comments from it. For example:

```
var text = 'This is not a comment\n/*this is a comment*/\nNot a comment/*Another comment*/';
var comments = getComments(text);
```

And 'comments' will be an array with the values:

```
['this is a comment', 'Another comment']
```

I tried with this code:

```
function getComments(text) {
    var comments,
    comment,
    regex;

    comments = [];
    regex = /\/\*([^\/\*]*)\*\//g;
    comment = regex.exec(text);

    while(comment !== null) {
        skewer.log(comment);
        comments.push(comment[1]);
        comment = regex.exec(text);
    }

    return comments;
}
```

The problem is that if there is a * or a */* inside the comment, it does not match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code a bit in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/noelstieglitz/rkdzjb9s/), removing some of the ancillary code (like skewer).  Here is the relevant part:

```
function getComments(text) {
    var comments,
    regex,
    match;
    comments = [];
    regex = /\/\*.*?\*\//g

    while ((match = regex.exec(text)) != null) {
        comments.push(match);
    }
    return comments;
}
```

Comment: This only works with *most* but not all the cases. Take `var a = "/*"; var b = "*/";` for example - no comment should be extracted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the JavaScript piece, but this regex should match your pattern: `\/\*.*?\*\/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, works on php and javascript:

```
(?:\/\*)((.|[\r\n])*?)(?:\*\/)
```

You can test on: https://regex101.com/r/qoeQLq/2